# How do you make sum of multiple columns made with separate query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I made table with multiple columns and each columns have separate query. How do I add this?

```
select
(select count(x) from table1 a, table2 b where ~~;) as column1,
(select count(x) from table3 a, table4 b where ~~;) as column2,
(select count(x) from table5 a, table6 b where ~~;) as column3,
(column1 + column2 + column3) as total
from dual;
```

Above query works if each column is from same table but in this case, Oracle SQL tells me column1, 2, 3 are invalid identifier in total line.

How do I make this work? :(

Comment: are you sure about semi-colons ..?

Comment: I would use laterals, ie `select c1, c2, c3, c1+c2+c3 from dual, lateral(Select... as c1 from...), lateral(Select... as c2 from...), lateral(Select... as c3 from...) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only refer to a column alias - like `column1` here - in an order-by clause. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html):

> **c_alias**
>
> Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The `AS` keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the *order_by_clause* but not other clauses in the query.

You can use a subquery to get the calculated columns, and then use the aliases to perform further work outside that subquery, either in a CTE or an inline view:

```
select column1, column2, column3, (column1 + column2 + column3) as total
from (
  select
    (select count(x) from table1 a, table2 b where ~~) as column1,
    (select count(x) from table3 a, table4 b where ~~) as column2,
    (select count(x) from table5 a, table6 b where ~~) as column3
  from dual
);
```

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that too but actual query is very long. lol. each column is made with 4+ tables joined and there are about 20 columns. so if I use another query on top of it like that, it will make this query 2x longer so I wanted to find if there was different way around instead of having 1000 lines of query. :D

Comment: Sounds like the whole query needs refactoring *8-) At least if the subqueries are referencing the same tables. The outer query only needs to refer to the aliases from the inner query though, so you aren't repeating the whole thing; and the calculation (total here) is move out from the inner query, so that isn't being repeated. Still, a CTE might be easier to manage than an inline view, even if there's no real difference in what they're doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use subquery:

```
select *, column1+column2+column3 as total from
(
select
(select count(x) from table1 a, table2 b where ...) as column1,
(select count(x) from table3 a, table4 b where ...) as column2,
(select count(x) from table5 a, table6 b where ...) as column3
from dual
) X
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
  select (select count(x) from table1 a, table2 b where ~~;) as column1,
         (select count(x) from table3 a, table4 b where ~~;) as column2,
         (select count(x) from table5 a, table6 b where ~~;) as column3
    from dual
)
select c.*, column1 + column2 + column3 as total
  from cte c;
```